# Core Data: Combining multiple similar rows into one

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities DatePaid (one attribute "datePaid":Date) and Expense(two attributes "amount": Float and "category": String). The relation ship between them is: 
DatePaid <---->> Expense.

I want to display the "datePaid", "amount" and "category" values retrieved from Model on table view section (one date per section) and the cell below each section displays "amount" and "category" paid on that day.

The case is that I have multiple similar values for "datePaid". 
For example:

```
"datePaid": 14.02.2017 <---->> "Category": "Food", "Amount": 10
"datePaid": 14.02.2017 <---->> "Category": "Clothes", "Amount": 20
"datePaid": 15.02.2017 <---->> "Category": "Services", "Amount": 30
```

And I want to combine those similar dates into one, which looks like:

```
"datePaid": 14.02.2017 <---->> "Category": "Food", "Amount": 10;
                               "Category": "Clothes", "Amount": 20
"datePaid": 15.02.2017 <---->> "Category": "Services", "Amount": 30
```

Is there any way that I can deal with this?

Thank you.